# Splitting 2 sentences fetched from text area in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using a text area in a jsp page. In a servlet, I am trying to fetch multiple lines from the text area. I used

```
textarea.getParameter("textarea");
```

and

```
textarea.getParameterValues("textarea");
```

both return 2 sentences in the text area with a newline in between them. My requirement is that I should use the 2 sentences in the text area separately. How do I separate the 2 sentences in servlet?

Edit:

The input is
[image: Input]

I need to get these two sentences in a servlet and split them and use them individually.

Comment: Is it always two lines? Or is it just that you want to split `n` lines of input into separate lines? In the first case I would use two inputs instead of one. In the second, check out [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @NilsH not just 2 lines, its n number of lines

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.lang.String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String s = "First sentence.\nSecond sentence.";
String[] sentences = s.split("\n");
System.out.println(sentences[0]);
System.out.println(sentences[1]);
```

Output:

```
First sentence.
Second sentence.
```

Comment: I tried using split("\n") but sentences[0] prints with newline and sentences[1] prints the same line (ie) sentences[0]: I am Rahul (A empty line in between) and then sentences[1]: I study MBA

Comment: Please inlcude the *exact* input you try to split. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28426653/edit) your question with it